# Computer was working and now won't turn on

Tags: windows-7, computer-building

Until recently my Windows 7 desktop computer was working fine. A few days ago I turned it off to install some Windows updates and now it won't turn on.

This problem has happened in the past but before I was able to fix it by unplugging the power cable from the PS and plugging it back in. I'm not sure why this worked but for some reason it isn't anymore. Does anyone know what could be causing this problem?

I don't see LEDs on my Gigabyte motherboard. The HDDs or fans don't spin up or anything.

I did the [PS test](http://www.howtogeek.com/172933/how-can-i-test-my-computers-power-supply/) and it passed. Might be a motherboard problem.

Comment: Do you mean you have no lights showing HDD activity & no fan movement ?

Comment: What a detailed question. A+

Comment: @The_IT_Guy_You_Don't_Like I added more to my question. When I hit the power button there's no activity what so ever. I'm trying to find what motherboard model I have but there's no defining marks on the top side of it.

Answer (score 0):

Try unplugging the cable from the computer, waiting a long time (at least 10 minutes, preferably 30), and then turning it on again.   Some PSU's have built in protections to prevent surges and, in some events, won't immediately turn back on - and each time you attempt to do it you "reset" the clock on how long it needs to be powered off for.

Answer (score 0):

seems like a faulty/failed power supply. Slim possibility your front-panel power switch has gone bad.  You could try the [paper clip test](https://www.google.ca/search?q=atx%20paperclip%20test) and see what results you get.

Comment: I did do the paper clip test and it passed!